# Creating an appointment to a specific calendar. VBA outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

How do i create a macro to create an appointment to another calendar. The current macro i am using creates to my default calendar. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub test()

Dim myItem As Object
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
myItem.Subject = "Strategy Meeting"
myItem.Location = "Conf Rm All Stars"
myItem.Start = #4/11/2016 1:30:00 PM#
myItem.Duration = 10
myItem.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean in another store already open in your profile? Or in a delegate Exchange mailbox?

Comment: A calendar that is shared with multiple users.

Comment: yes on theexchange server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient`, then pass the returned `Recipient` object to `Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder`. You can then call `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` to add a new appointment.