# Adding an appointment to a non-default calendar linked to iCloud

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar

I am attempting to add new appointments to a calendar linked using "iCloud for Windows". I have read everything I can find on the subject of Outlook and Calendars on this site and I have used OutlookSpy to navigate through the various objects and folders, (and I thank Dimitry for the huge help he has provided the coding community for this fabulous tool).

However, I am still unable to write to the non-default calendar.

Based on this answer, [Creating an appointment to a specific calendar. VBA outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538042/creating-an-appointment-to-a-specific-calendar-vba-outlook), here is my code...

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
...
Application app = new Application();
AppointmentItem appt = null;

app.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = 
app.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Recipient recipent = app.Session.CreateRecipient("Jobs"); 

appt = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
appt.Subject = "Subject goes here ...";
appt.Location = "Address/Suburb/State";
appt.Body = "Job GPS: " + "-1234567 987654";
appt.Start = DateTime.Now;
appt.End = appt.Start.AddHours(2);

app.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder.Items.Add(appt); <--- Fails here
```

I am uncertain whether it is the fact that the calendar I am wanting to write to is a non-Outlook calendar, or if I simply am missing something prior to attempting to save the appointment.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`MAPIFolder.Items.Add` only takes a string (message class) or one of the `OlItemType` enums (e.g. `OlItemType.olAppointmentItem` = 1)

You need to use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` instead of `GetDefaultFolder`, which you only use to reset the actively selected fodler in OUtlook (why?).

Comment: My thinking was to select the "Jobs" calendar inside the iCloud object, make it the default folder, and then add an appointment to it. Namespace("MAPI").GetSharedDefaultFolder requires a recipient and my code now errors on this command. Furthermore, now, I am unsure whether Recipient should be "iCloud", or "Jobs".

Comment: You should be something that can uniquely be resolved to that mailbox owner. If it is not an Exchange mailbox, then use Namespace.Stores to get the parent store of that folder, then call Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

Comment: Is there a difference between GetSharedDefaultFolder and a folder that is shared and not a default folder? My Outlook configuration includes 3 mailboxes, one of which has 2 additional aliases, plus an "iCal for Windows" calendar-only link to an Apple user's calendar. It is this last calendar that I need to insert appointments into. From your last comment, is it correct for me to think that I need to identify the store where this calendar is located first, and then get the default (shared) folder?

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder is Exchange-only. It does not sound like you are using Exchange.

Comment: My apologies Dmitry, I should have mentioned at the very beginning. We are using Office 365 (but Outlook is locally installed on each PC).

Comment: So the other store is an Exchange mailbox? Then GetSharedDefaultFolder will work.

Comment: The other store is not an Exchange mailbox. When I iterate through the folders it tells me it is

Comment: The other store is not an Exchange mailbox. The Store.IsDataStore property is false, and the Store.IsCachedExchange is also false.

Comment: Then, as I mentioned before - If it is not an Exchange mailbox, then use Namespace.Stores to get the parent store of that folder, then call Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

Comment: Store does not have a method of GetDefaultFolder(). I have looped through all the NameSpace.Stores and gotten my "iCloud" store, set the.RootFolder then looped through its sub folders to get the "Jobs folder, but I do not understand how to set that folder as the current folder so my appointment will save int it , rather than the original default folder. Should I be using NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder?

Comment: What "context" do I need to be in to save my appointment in the chosen calendar? Do I need to set the current folder, or just the current store? And how do I do that once I have navigated to it?

Comment: Store object was added in Outlook 2012. What version of Outlook are you using? Is your interop up to date?

Comment: Outlook version 15... I do not know what version of InterOp. I will check when I get back to the office and let you know.

Comment: Outlook version 16. InterOp version 15.

Comment: 14 and up should be fine. Try to remove the Outlook reference and add it from the COM tab.

Comment: @MarkChimes Did you get anywhere with this?  Trying to do the same thing.